# Can I use RGeo::Point data in PostGIS queries without multiple conversion?

Tags: postgis, ruby

How can I represent RGeo::Point ( CAPI implementation ) in some way where I don't have to convert it once more in Sql?

Now I have something like this:

```
class Poly
  scope :enclosing ->(geom) do
    where ["ST_Contains(poly.geom, ST_GeomFromText( ? , 4326))",
           geom.as_text]
  end
end
...
p = RGeo::Geos.factory(srid: 4326).point(10, 20)
Poly.enclosing(p)
```

This way the point first gets represented as `"POINT (10.0 20.0)"` , then converted to geometry by `ST_GeomFromText`. Is there a shortcut? PostGIS geometry items look like `0101000020E6100000CC79C6BE64E13D4046F6F708EB8F4E40` and have SRID already encoded, but RGeo::Point.as_binary returns something very different and not acceptable by PostGIS.